# Backbone destroy a model outside of a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a `UserPanel` view, which uses a `UserModel` as its model. In the template for the `UserPanel`, I have a conditional that checks whether or not the model is `undefined`. If the model exists, it displays user information. If it doesn't, it displays the "registration" form.

On the user information part of the `UserPanel`, I have what's essentially an "unregister" button. A user clicks it, and the user information is deleted. The `UserPanel` responds by re-rendering, allowing them to register a different `UserModel`.

Common sense tells me to call [this.model.destroy](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy). When I use this method, my model is deleted from my data store, but the object still exists in `this.model`. When the view responds to the model update (by calling `render`), it still thinks it has a valid model, with all its data and the like. I can call delete on `this.model`, but that doesn't trigger any events. I can't trigger the event before I `delete`, because then the view updates before I can delete the model. I have setup the view to respond to model deletions with a method that simply uses `delete` on the model, then calls `render`. This works, but bothers me on a conceptual level, since those methods are for handling view updates and not more model manipulation.

In general, what's the proper way to explicitly dispose of a model that is not stored by a collection?

EDIT: I am using [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) as my data store. This might have something to do with it.

Comment: some actual code would be nice

Comment: https://gist.github.com/raynjamin/7326945#file-derp-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding to the `destroy` event I would use the success callback of the `model.destroy` like so:

```
this.model.destroy({ success: _.bind(this.onModelDestroySuccess, this) });
```

Then rename your `modelDestroyedView` to `onModelDestroySuccess`:

```
onModelDestroySuccess: function () {
  delete this.model;
  this.render();
},
```

I would also define a `cleanupModelEvents` method that cleans up your event bindings to the model:

```
cleanupModelEvents: function() {
  this.stopListening(this.model);
},
```

And call that from `onModelDestroySuccess`:

```
onModelDestroySucess: function () {
  this.cleanupModelEvents();
  delete this.model;
  this.render();
},
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.model.destroy();
```

and then on the `destroy` event

```
this.model = null;
```